# How to remember device without device id

Tags: android, device, identification

supposedly there is no such thing as deviceId in android. However, some apps are able to track my phone. And what I mean is, if I install the app, uninstall, then reinstall: the app remembers my device. How is that accomplished?

For completeness accounts are created using phone numbers. I create an account using a `Google/Voice` -- not my actual device -- phone number. Then I use my account for some user interactions. I deleted the app, then a few days later reinstalled. The app remembered me. I didn't need to re-register the "fake" phone number or anything.

Also my phone is Galaxy S5.

Comment: Does the app have write access to storage and leave a special file in an out of the way place?

Comment: I don't know. It's not my app. I just notice an app was able to do it. And I've been wanting to do it.

Comment: One popular app that I'm aware of does leave a special file in a special directory to keep track of usage and as long as the file is still there on install "remembers" prior usage.

Answer (score 3):

> supposedly there is no such thing as deviceId in android

Sure there is: `ANDROID_ID`. Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#ANDROID_ID):

> A 64-bit number (as a hex string) that is randomly generated when the user first sets up the device and should remain constant for the lifetime of the user's device. The value may change if a factory reset is performed on the device.
>
> Note: When a device has multiple users (available on certain devices running Android 4.2 or higher), each user appears as a completely separate device, so the ANDROID_ID value is unique to each user.

Now, [it's not an absolute guarantee](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html):

> First, it is not 100% reliable on releases of Android prior to 2.2 (“Froyo”). Also, there has been at least one widely-observed bug in a popular handset from a major manufacturer, where every instance has the same ANDROID_ID.

Also, those who root their device can presumably mess with this value, and I forget what emulators do for this value.

There also may be limits on your use of this value imposed by your app distribution channel of choice. For example, I forget if the Play Store has rules around the use of this value, particularly related to advertising.

There may be other bugs surrounding `ANDROID_ID` as well. Personally, I find this sort of tracking to be offensive, so I haven't looked into this in ages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you by any chance how to get this ANDROID_ID?

Comment: @KatedralPillon: Use `getString()`, presumably: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html#getString%28android.content.ContentResolver,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 0):

You can use [InstanceId](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/) for this purpose.

Comment: This seems like a handy tool as well. I will look into it. But the very name suggest it is not what I am looking for. Since "Instance" should not survive uninstalls. But I will look into it. Thanks.